# setContentView xml file error

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm training my java skills in android studio.
In my java HomeActivity i try to use xml file in my application with using

```
setContentView(R.layout.home_layout)
```

but android studio all time shows my error. I was clean, rebuild my app and reset android studio but still i have mistake. I haven't any idea i was looking any solution on this forum but still isn't working correct

This is a full code of HomeActivity.java

```
package my.domain.appname;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import android.R;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); AppCompatActivity

        setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
    }

    public void OnNextClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, AboutProgram.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I will thankful for help

Comment: Please attach error stack trace and xml file

Comment: Also consider including the layout XML file for `home_layout`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that xml file is correct because android studio doesn't show any error in xml but i attach code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:background="#748494" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="any text"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="casual"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="any text"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="casual"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:shadowColor="#571b1b" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="any text"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="any text"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="any text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:onClick="OnNextClick"/> 

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put your `xmlns:android` first and than your `android:background`, remove `/>` near last `</LinearLayout>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your xml need to look like:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#748494"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="any text"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:fontFamily="casual"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="any text"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="casual"
    android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
    android:shadowColor="#571b1b" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="any text"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="any text"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="any text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
    android:onClick="OnNextClick"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all for help with xml code. Now app is works correctly but the solution of mistake is very strange for me. In home HomeActivity.java i deleted line `import android.R;` and app was running. Would you like to tell my with this solutions was correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is finding the .xml file for the Home screen. For this you should try creating .xml file of the home_layout.